# KDE fails with two points?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, kernel-density

The following trivial example returns a singular matrix. Why? Any ways to overcome it?

```
In: from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
Out:

In:  points
Out: (array([63, 84]), array([46, 42]))

In:  gaussian_kde(points)
Out: (array([63, 84]), array([46, 42]))

LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the backtrace, you can see it fails when inverting the covariance matrix. This is due to exact [multicollinearity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity) of your data. From the page, you have multicollinearity in your data if two variables are collinear, i.e. if

> the correlation between two independent variables is equal to 1 or -1

In this case, the two variables have only two samples, and they are always collinear (trivially, there exists always one line passing two distinct points). We can check that:

```
np.corrcoef(array([63,84]),array([46,42]))
[[ 1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.]]
```

To not be necessarily collinear, two variables must have at least `n=3` samples. To add to this constraint, you have the limitation pointed out by ali_m, that the number of samples `n` should be greater or equal to the number of variables `p`. Putting the two together,

```
n>=max(3,p)
```

in this case `p=2` and `n>=3` is the right constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when `gaussian_kde()` tries to take the inverse of the covariance matrix of your input data. In order for the covariance matrix to be nonsingular, the number of (non-identical) points in your input must be >= to the number of variables. Try adding a third point and you should see that it works.

[This answer on Crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60622/why-is-a-sample-covariance-matrix-singular-when-sample-size-is-less-than-number) has a proper explanation for why this is the case.

Comment: @flebool D'oh - not sure how missed that! Yes, of course you're right, Having `n >= p` is a necessary but not sufficient condition - the covariance matrix can still be rank-deficient if you have multicollinearity.